# Does spring integration has a SAX xpath-header-enricher?

Tags: xpath, spring-integration

I've seen that the implementation of the xpath-header-enricher uses DOM, is there a SAX implementation I can use?

I'm using SI 4.3.16.RELEASE

Thanks in advance
Regards
Guzmán

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. It's not clear how it would work since

"SAX parsers operate on each piece of the XML document sequentially, issuing parsing events while making a single pass through the input stream."